# For which values of $x$, $0$°$≤x<360$°, is $\sin x > \cos x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry, inequality

> For which values of $x$ such that  $0$°$≤x<360$°, we have: $\sin x > \cos x$?

The answer is "When $45$° $< x < 225°$, the $y$-coordinate of the point on the unit circle is greater than the $x$-coordinate", but I don't understand why this is the answer and how the book got it.

Comment: Draw a diagonal line $x=y$. The open half-plane towards the upper-left (the half-plane that contains $(-1, 1)$) is the set of $(x,y)$ pair where $y>x$. Then the idea in your book is to intersect with (the set of points on) a unit circle, where $x = \cos \theta$ and $y = \sin \theta$.

Answer (score 0):

It's $\sin(x-45^{\circ})>0$, which gives $0^{\circ}<x-45^{\circ}<180^{\circ}$